# Where are SQL statements stored after generating a database.yml file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating my FirstApp, I used sqlite3 database to manipulate my transactions. I changed my `database.yml` file to be compatible with MySQL2 and also installed MySQL2 gem. I migrated the database to MySQL by using rake command and deleted the sqlite3 database from the db directory. Now, whenever I try to store new data I get this error:

> SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: INSERT INTO "movies" ("title", "description", "movie_length", "director", "rating", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Where can I find the files where the queries are written? How can I store them in MySQL?

Comment: Are you sure you've changed "adapter" in database.yml ?

Comment: Yes I have add mysql2 as a adapter

Comment: You can try to clear cache with "rake tmp:clear" ? About your Gemfile ? Have you removed gem sqlite3 and added mysql2 ?

Comment: Thanks Now its perfectly working.

Comment: I'm glad to have been useful.